# list all sub directories containing certain file, then copy those directories somewhere

Tags: bash, directory, copy, find

from my current directory I have subdirectories. I would like to list a subdirectory that contains files ending in `449.ss`.

I can do this by:

```
find . -iname "*-449.ss" | sed -e 's!/[^/]*$!!' -e 's!^\./!!' | sort -u
```

however I want to copy all of these directories to a new directory `correct`. I have tried

```
$ find . -iname "*-449.ss" | sed -e 's!/[^/]*$!!' -e 's!^\./!!' | sort -u | xargs -0 -I{} cp -r {} correct/
cp: cannot stat `polyid4ssnps105\npolyid4ssnps106\npolyid4ssnps107\n': File name too long
```

where I tried passing to `xargs`. However this has treated the list as a single string.

where have I gone wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xargs -l ...
```

and remove parameter `-0` also

man xargs:

> ```
>    -l[max-lines], --max-lines[=max-lines]
>           Synonym for the -L option.  Unlike -L, the max-lines argument is
>           optional.  If max-lines is not specified, it  defaults  to  one.
>           The  -l  option is deprecated since the POSIX standard specifies
>           -L instead.
> ```